# CakePHP change error.log or debug.log file name

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

By changing [/Cake/Log/Engine/Filelog.php](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/file-log#line-58)'s write function I can change "error.log" and "debug.log" file names.

Is there any way to change these file names without hacking CakePHP 2 core files.

Comment: why would you want to? they contain errors and debug information, seems fitting. You can create additional log files i.e. `CakeLog::write('my_log', 'message');` and cake will create a log file called `my_log`)

Comment: Because there exists no size limitation. If I don't care for 2 weeks I had an error.log file which is 2 megabytes. I want to add **date("d-m-Y)** to file name.

Comment: you then should use similar approaches as logrotate does. moving its content into "error-x.log" files leaving the newest primary file as it is: name "error.log". you can do that with a crontask cronjob on a regular basis for example. no need to put this overhead into the application layer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment above, you said that the reason you're wanting to change the names of these log files is because the files in question have no size limitations. The thing is: If you have an error log that is 2MB in size, then you've clearly got bigger fish to fry. As far as I know, there is no way to change those file names without hacking the core. If you're really worried about the size of those two log files, then you ***could*** setup a cronjob that checks the size of those two files every 24 hours. If the log file size is bigger than the predetermined limit that you've set, you could send an alert email to yourself. To be honest: The best approach to take is to test your application extensively beforehand so that any entry in those two files becomes a surprise instead of a routine.

Answer (score 2):

As of CakePHP 2.4.0 this feature is added: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/markstory/2013/08/30/cakephp_2_4_0_is_ready

> FileLogs can now have a max size and simple rotation configured.

[Filelog](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-FileLog.html) class has file size limit and number of files to rotate.

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt config to get what you want. But you can easily make your custom logger class which extends `FileLog` and override the relevant function and use that.

Answer (score 0):

in cake 3 you can set rotate config easily in /config/app.php

```
'Log' => [
     'error' => [
          'className' => 'Cake\Log\Engine\FileLog',
          'rotate'=>2,
           //other config
```

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 2 you can change same configuration in /app/config/bootstrap.php:

```
CakeLog::config('debug', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'types' => array('notice', 'info', 'debug'),
    'file' => 'debug',
));
CakeLog::config('error', array(
    'engine' => 'File',`enter code here`
    'types' => array('warning', 'error', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency'),
    'file' => 'error',
));
```